# Color stack action is missing & Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: color, numbering, ref, undefined

I am writing my thesis and I have roughly a lot of packages that were used during my research. Which could confuse the latex?

I got a number of errors, and references do not show up.

- Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation(subcaption) with the subfig package. \begin{document}
- Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}

```
%\documentclass[12pt]{IEEEtran}
%\documentclass[11pt,modernstyle]{thesis}
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{siugrad51}
%\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{thesis} 
%\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\iffalse
\textwidth=6in \oddsidemargin=0.5in \topmargin=-0.5in
\textheight=9in  % 9in must include page numbers
\textfloatsep = 0.4in \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{0.4in} \hfill
Page\endgraf} \addtocontents{lof}{\vspace{0.2in} \hspace{0.13in} \
Figure\hfill Page\endgraf} \addtocontents{lot}{\vspace{0.2in}
\hspace{0.13in} \ Table\hfill Page\endgraf}
\fi
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/SIU850607993/Documents/Conferences/CLOUD-2017/fig/}}


\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amsbsy,bm}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{rotating}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{stmaryrd}
 \usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{eepic}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
%\usepackage[tocgraduated]{tocstyle}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath} 
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[subfigure, titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\renewcommand{\nomname}{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
\makenomenclature
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png,.PNG, .eps, .tiff}

\urlstyle{same}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{7}


 \begin{document}

%\pagestyle{myheadings} \markright{\today}

\pagenumbering{alph}

\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}\enlargethispage{\the\footskip}%
\begin{center}
    { {\textbf{XXXXXXX}}\par }%
    \vskip.4in
    Author
    
    {XXXX}
    \vskip .3in
    Supervisors
    
    {Dr. XXXX\\
        Dr. XXXX\\
        Dr. XXXX}
    \vskip .3in
    
    \begin{doublespace}
        XXXXXX\\
        PH.D. RESEARCH PROPOSAL\\ [.1in]
    \end{doublespace}
    A thesis submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements\\
    for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy\\
    in the
    Department of Computer Science\\
    in the Graduate School\\
    XXXXXX
\end{center}
%%%Uncomment for Signatures%%%

%\\[.14in]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%Uncomment  for Approved Names%%%%%%
%\begin{center}
%\begin{doublespace}
%Approved:\\
%Professor John D. Doe \\
%Professor Jane D. Doe
%\end{doublespace}
%\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\input{abstract}
%\doublespacing
\pagenumbering{roman} \setcounter{page}{2}


\tableofcontents



%\listoftables
\newpage
%\listoffigures
\newpage


\normalsize
%\doublespacing
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%------------------------------------------------SECTION------------------------------------------------%
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%


\input{introduction}
\input{relatedwork}
%\input{analysis}
\input{architecture}
%\input{algorithm}
\input{evaluaiton}
\input{conclusion}
\input{introduction2}
\input{relwork2}
\input{analysis2}
\input{architecture2}
\input{conclusion2}
\input{summary}

\begin{spacing}{0.88}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{cloud}
\end{spacing}




\end{document}
```

Comment: The error message already tells you what's wrong. You simply can not use both packages `subfig` and `subcaption` in one document. Just keep one and remove the other one.

Comment: Apart from that, your preamble would definitely benefit from a serious clean up. Do not load packages more than once, especially not with conflicting options. `\usepackage{colortbl}` is not needed, since it is already loaded by `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`. `hyperref` should (with a few exceptions) be the last package in your preamble...

Comment: @leandriis, thank you for some tips. Now, I only have the errors that show in the title of the post. I no longer have figure issues.